# How can I .dex file to jar type from Windows command line?

Tags: java, android, decompiling

Below is the code I entered in a Windows command prompt, and the failure it's giving. I added classes.dex of my apk to dex2jar, and set the path in the command windows, but it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

```
    C:\test\dex2jar-2.0> d2j-dex2jar.bat classes.dex
dex2jar classes.dex -> .\classes-dex2jar.jar
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: .\classes-dex2jar.jar
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.<init>(ZipFileSystem.java:116)
        at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:139)
        at com.googlecode.d2j.dex.Dex2jar.createZip(Dex2jar.java:288)
        at com.googlecode.d2j.dex.Dex2jar.to(Dex2jar.java:271)
        at com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.Dex2jarCmd.doCommandLine(Dex2jarCmd.java:108)
        at com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.BaseCmd.doMain(BaseCmd.java:288)
        at com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.Dex2jarCmd.main(Dex2jarCmd.java:32)
C:\test\dex2jar-2.0>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately questions like these are off-topic because they have nothing to do with programming, and therefore should be closed as [blatantly off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: it reads `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException` ...which is coming from the illegal syntax used at `dot backslash`. voted to close this because of typo, and off-topic might apply, too.